# pip install with python dependencies problem

Tags: rhel, python, pip

we are installing the pip ( pip 20.1.1 ) on our RHEL 7.6 server as

```
tar -xvzf pip-20.1.1.tar.gz -C /install
cd /install/pip-20.1.1
python setup.py install
```

we get exception as

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'project_urls'

warning.warn(msg)

Traceback (most recent call last):

File stup.py line 87 in module

python_requires => 2.7, !=3, !=3.1, !=3.2, !=3.3, !=3.4
```

not clear why this exception since we have the installed the following python version

```
python python2 python2.7 python2.7-config python-config python3 python-config
```

setuptool version is:

```
easy_install --version
setuptools 44.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (Python 2.7)
```

Comment: Why aren’t you using the `python3-pip` available from RHEL?

Comment: Also, installing software via pip as root is extremely dangerous and can easily leave your system broken.  Use Python packages from reputable sources or install in a virtualenv or as a non-root user.

Comment: you have conflict about your two notes , on the first note you say use pip to install modules , and on the second note you say not use pip install <modules> because  system broken

Comment: anyway we not get answer about , what we need to do about the problem , since I used "python setup.py install" that installed PIP2

Comment: You can use pip, just not as root or outside of a virtualenv, so I am not being inconsistent. I just suggest you not install random python modules as root outside of packages provided by trusted vendors. But as you are running an one of life RHEL you probably don’t care about system integrity.

Comment: Backing all that @jsbillings says. Here's a more thorough explanation why you [never run pip as root](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/do-not-run-pip-as-root#:~:text=So%20when%20you%20invoke%20pip,and%20pip%20installed%20Python%20modules.), *especially* on CentOS/RHEL systems.